# Execute javascript after ClientSideValidation

Tags: javascript, vb.net

I'm using a bunch of standard asp RequiredFieldValidars in a vb.net web application. What I would like to be able to do is to execute a Javascript function at the end of each attempt to perform client side validation. The function needs to execute after all the validators have been run and the pages validation summary has been displayed.

Could someone tell me if this is possible and point me in the right direction please?

```
function ValidationComplete() {
 // Run me after validation has been performed
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've worked it out. For anyone else who has this problem, I did the following:

Set the CausesValidation property of the submit button to False and the onclientclick property to a proxy Javascript function.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" CausesValidation="False" onclientclick="return DetailsValidation()" />
```

On your page on in your Javascript file add the proxy function which calls the .net validation Javascript and acts depending on the result. Returning false to top page submission and true to allow it.

```
function DetailsValidation() {
    Page_ClientValidate();
    if (Page_IsValid) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        CustomAfterValidation();
        return false;
    }
}
```

In this instance CustomAfterValidation is called after the .Net validation has been performed and if the page isn't valid.